# Determination of equivalent resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

I need to calculate the equivalent resistance of this circuit which seems easy in the start as it looks like there are several parallel circuits. But as you can see there are 2 black lines connecting the red circuit and the green circuit. From here I don't know how to calculate the equivalent resistance if 2 smaller parallel circuits (the red and the green one) are connected.

[image]

Comment: No points for posing an EE question as an exercise in Topology.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the arrows in your diagram are of any significance, as far as I can see all 10 resistors are in parallel. Two groups of resistors on parallel, when connected in parallel with each other just look like one bigger group of parallel resistors. Your circuit is equivalent to :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnW11L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>